# WinJS won't allow me to attach event handlers to dynamically created HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

I first tried the easy yet disapproved way of creating elements with `innerHTML`**:**

```
// "Alarms" is a div that will contain the new divs
document.getElementById("Alarms").innerHTML += "<div onclick=\"watevr\">";
```

But Visual Studio told me I'm not allowed to insert JavaScript like that, then I tried the right/other way:

```
var alarms = document.getElementById("Alarms");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "I'm the new div!";
div.onclick = "watevr";
alarms.appendChild(div);
```

Now whenever I run my code I get this error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

and the code breaks at `alarms.appendChild(div);`

I've tried `div.addEventListener("click", function(){watevr}, false);` instead of `onclick` to no avail.

Interestingly, removing `div.onclick = "watevr";` fixes the problem completely.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to put all your code in a separate file then create a self execute fucntion like this:

```
(function(){

   var MyApp {

       init : function(){

            this.renderMyDiv();     

       },

       renderMyDiv: function(){

          var alarms = document.getElementById("Alarms");
          var element = document.createElement('div');
          element.className = 'superDiv';
          element.innerHTML = 'Im the div';
          alarms.appendChild(element);
          this.addDivEvent('superDiv');

       }

       addDivEvent: function(className){

          var element = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
          for(var i = 0, j=element.length; i<j; i++){
                  element[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                       //TO-DO
                  }
          }

       }

   }

   MyApp.init();

})();
```

This is the old way to do it but you can also accomplish this vía jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 - You don't want to attach listeners via attributes anyway, so don't bother.

Problem 2 - You seem to have a bug causing getElementById to return null or undefined. From your text it looks like you're saying createElement returned null, but that shouldn't be possible so I'm assuming you just pasted the wrong code and/or error.

Problem 3 - You're using innerHTML in the second block to add non-HTML text.

Problem 4 - You're assigning a string to the onclick property (it should be a function).

Using createElement, appendChild, and either onclick or addEventListener is the right approach. Don't adding to innerHTML unless you really need to insert HTML. Since the string doesn't contain anything dynamic I don't see why it would mark the element as u trusted, but maybe it does... If that is the case, you can either:
A) Use innerText.
B) Create more elements directly or using a template or fragment.
C) Call toStaticHTML on the string before assigning to innerHTML.
4) Wrap the call that adds the element to the DOM in an MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction call.

But you'll need to fix your null dereference bugs first.